# Ionic - ion-view title not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm following some of the examples from the website and my current html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Test">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view>
        <!-- Center content -->
    </ion-nav-view>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
        <ion-view view-title="Home">
            <ion-content >
                <p>
                   Test
                </p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the js:

```
var app = angular.module('Test', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl'

  })
})

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

Now the documentation says the view-title="Test" should fill the title in ion-navbar. But it doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows what is going wrong?

Comment: try title="Test" instead of view-title="Test"?

Comment: Ok..I added with docs URL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that it can be used in both ways,

```
<ion-view view-title="My Page">
```

or

```
<ion-nav-title>
    {{page.title}}
</ion-nav-title>
```

as per latest version of ionic.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavTitle/

Comment: For those who run into a similar issue; using view-title gave me problems when using dynamic titles. Switching to ion-nav-title resolved this. (using ionic 1.1.0)

Comment: For more info on the solution proposed by @SaW: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/12/18/is-your-ionic-view-title-not-updating/

Answer (score 5):

This should work,

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title> Your title here
  </ion-nav-title>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Note, ion-nav-title should be placed inside ion-nav-bar as of 1.0.0.rc.1

Answer (score 1):

Switch to using `<ion-nav-title>`

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-title>{{navTitle}}</ion-nav-title>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div>
        <p>The opening crawl would go here.</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

[click to read more](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/12/18/is-your-ionic-view-title-not-updating/)

Answer (score -3):

Ionic is continuously working and they would updating the directives in upcoming releases and I assume that you are using old version.

As per the `1.0.0-beta.13` doc, Attribute should be `title` instead of `view-title`

Change the following line

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
```

to

```
<ion-view title="Home">
```

Old version Doc: http://ionicframework.com/docs/1.0.0-beta.13/api/directive/ionView/

But in latest version, it should be `view-title`

Latest doc: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: then how do you explain `<ion-view view-title="Also Factual">` from  http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/ ?

Comment: I am not familiar on ionic. anyway, where is the "view-title" directive used in the above said url?

Comment: i saw it [here](http://codepen.io/ionic/embed/odqCz?height=568&theme-id=3572&slug-hash=odqCz&default-tab=result&user=ionic#html-box) - under the HTML tab; it is also true that I tried to copy the example and `view-title` does not work and had to change it to `title`; i guess it is just a beta thing; would you recommend another framework for Cordova?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar on mobile apps but I am going to start studying on ionic framework. I believe this will be rocks in near future.

Comment: are you sure its `title` ? I can see in document its `view-title` !

Comment: My guess is correct!! see this old version doc http://ionicframework.com/docs/1.0.0-beta.10/api/directive/ionView/ anyway, I will update my answer